# Transferring SSH session

Tags: ssh

I want to grab a process running in the sever via PC1 ssh X11 session to PC2 ssh session without stopping it. I cannot use "nohup" or "bg" or "screen" or any such command which works from that particular session. I have created virtual displays in the server.

**Why?**

I cannot access PC1, because it is hanged. But as the program is running in the server, that is unaffected as long as PC1 is on. Now I want to use PC1 which I can achieve by a single restart but that will stop the process running in the server.

Answer (score 1):

For running programs this is pretty much impossible, as PC1's X server keeps a lot of state about the program's graphical windows, and there are no tools to extract/migrate it.

Even if there were such tools, they'd be useless now since PC1 is hung so you couldn't ask it for migration data anyway.

In the future, consider running the program under [xpra](https://www.xpra.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux?  If so, there's a hack called [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) that might allow you to recover some control here.

If you're on another OS, you're probably out of luck, although there was some talk a while ago of adding a fully working way of [shipping processes between ttys](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-kern/2014/12/07/msg018214.html) to NetBSD.

Comment: reptyr does not work for x11 processes like matlab